# Don't use Google and APKPure misbehaves - how do I update apps?

Tags: applications, updates, redmi, apkpure

I have RedMi 3s (Android 6.0.1) phone. Also, I don't like Google, don't use their email and don't work with a Google account - so I don't use the Google Play Store.

For a few years, I have been using the APK Pure app to update all of my other apps. But - a while ago (perhaps early this year?) - somehow, it kind of stopped working. That is, it recognizes the apps that need updates, but never manages to actually get the updates going.

So what I'm looking for is another method/venue/app for routinely updating my apps. Preferably - one in which I don't have to actually press "INSTALL" for every single update, but I'm willing to live with that.

Alternatively, if I could someone overcome my APK Pure issue, that would be good too.

Any ideas?

Note: Manually updating individual apps works fine.

Comment: Maybe switch to APKMirror or one of the [other alternatives](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets#group_1182)? Not sure whether a non-system app can do automated installs/updates, though.

Comment: @Izzy: Isn't APKMirror based on you manually searching and navigating their site, rather than itself finding the relevant updates?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the apkpure app, or cleared at least it's data? have you tried to manually update an app? May be you don't get any updates because there are no longer updates for your apps on Android 6? Have you checked the Android logcat for errors?

Comment: @einpoklum I've never tried it (I'm using F-Droid and nothing else), so I cannot tell. Hence just the comment as possible pointer.

Comment: @Robert: I've just reinstalled APKPure - no effect. It still won't update apps, even when I press their "Update" button. Also - manual updates from APKs I downloaded myself - work. Also - there are updates for my apps.

Comment: You could try Aurora Store from F-Droid. It uses anonymous accounts to access the Play Store itself.

Comment: @Grimoire: I was going to try some of the alternatives Izzy linked to (already tried SkyDroid, which doesn't do what I need), but this sounds promising.

Comment: @Grimoire: Ok, I installed Aurora Store, and it seems like it should do what I wanted - but it just fails silently. You press "Update selected" or "Update All", it pauses for a half-second, then concludes with nothing happening. I've filed a [bug](https://gitlab.com/AuroraOSS/AuroraStore/-/issues/449) about this.

Comment: I see the same issue on an A70. I can't believe that updating apps from apkpure simply doesn't work: can anyone confirm that when they start apkpure and see the list of apps with pending updates, they can tap "update all" or "update" (for a specific app) and that it works?

Comment: Just made a bit of progress: managed to update individual apps after clearing app data (clearing cache didn't help). Still haven't managed to get "update all" to work, though. Interestingly, the button says "pause all" instead of "update all" even before I've triggered an update.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, [Aurora Store](https://github.com/whyorean/AuroraStore) worked for me. It's an app which access Google Play without requiring the user to have an account there or to provide his credentials.

On the other hand, APK Pure stopped misbehaving on mi MI 9 SE. Not sure if the problem was on my end or with the APK Pure app itself.