# PlayStore does not update APKMirror apps

Tags: google-play-store, security, updates, apk

I have an Android device where I have not assigned any Google account to it, just because I don't like/trust Google.

Since I cannot use the PlayStore to get apps without assigning an account (thanks for that Google...), I have downloaded some APKs from APKMirror.

Now, I see that the pre-installed Google apps get updated by the PlayStore, but the ones I have installed manually, after downloading them from APKMirror, don't. Despite the fact that I have read somewhere that this should work and that apps should be updating.

Is this some new Google way of forcing things down our throats?

Am I missing something?

What is the best way to not use a Google account and have apps update automatically?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Looks like there's a similar question: [Don't use Google and APKPure misbehaves - how do I update apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230410/44325). Does it help?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks a lot. That looks like what I was looking for. Hopefully, the solutions posted there still work... I don't know if Google realizes this, but this can be filed as a huge security issue to their platform, which they have created on purpose...